# Adding JDBC Driver to PySpark on Startup not Using Config File

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I am trying to use JDBC in Spark to read from a MS SQL table (in Azure) and save it as a parquet file (either locally or to S3). I have this working locally but I can't get it to work when Spark is on EC2.

My local version works because I manually opened my spark-defaults.conf file and add this**:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/<my_user>/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar:/Users/<my_user>/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/sqljdbc4.jar
```

** I only need mssql for this specific use case

Using EC2 I tried doing the following:

```
wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/2/A/02AAE597-3865-456C-AE7F-613F99F850A8/sqljdbc_6.0.7130.100_enu.tar.gz

tar -xf sqljdbc_6.0.7130.100_enu.tar.gz

ls 

./spark/bin/pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0 --driver-class-path "/root/sqljdbc_6.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar"
```

Then from within Python I do this:

```
sqlserver_user = <my_sql_user>
sqlserver_pw = <my_sql_pw>

sqlserver_<my_database>_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://<my_server>.cloudapp.net:<port_num>;DatabaseName=<my_db>;user=<my_user>;password=<my_password>;"

my_jdbc_test = sqlContext.load(
    source="jdbc", 
    url=sqlserver_<my_database>_url, 
    dbtable=<my_table>
    )

my_jdbc_test.printSchema()
```

The `my_jdbc_test.printSchema()` correctly displays the schema:

```
>>> my_jdbc_test.printSchema() 
root
 |-- my_var1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- my_var2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- my_var3: string (nullable = false)

>>>
```

Yet when I try to save it to my local disk as a parquet file I get a driver error:

```
my_jdbc_test.write.save("my_jdbc_test", format="parquet")

No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://<my_server>.cloudapp.net:<port_num>;DatabaseName=<my_db>;user=<my_user>;password=<my_password>;
```

Since it properly displays the schema I'm assuming it's becase the jar was added to the master but perhaps the source of the error is it isn't getting pushed out to the worker nodes? I searched a ton and couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try: my_jdbc_test.write.save("my_jdbc_test.parquet", format="parquet") ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the issue information, it was caused by the SQL Database driver & connection string. The jdbc driver & connection string are used for Java, not for Python.

So you need to use the odbc driver and connection string for Python, please try to install the Python package `pymssql` to access the SQL Database via refer to the doc http://pymssql.org/en/stable/.

The connection string for ODBC with Python is as below.

> `Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=tcp:<your-server>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<my_db>;Uid=<your-username>@<your-server>;Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30;`

If you have to use the jdbc driver and connection string, you can try to refer to the document [`Databases and Jython: Object Relational Mapping and Using JDBC`](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/DatabasesAndJython.html) using in Jython instead of Python.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer because the JDBC works perfectly fine when I modify the config file (e.g., my local example above); I'm merely trying to point to it during initialization via the command line and not via the config file. So to me this isn't actually a JDBC question because that all works fine, this is a PySpark initialization question: how do I point to a JAR file during startup that gets the JDBC driver to all nodes? I have the driver working on the master or the `printSchema()` wouldn't work.